# How to hide a <Div> using PHP

Tags: php, authentication, logout

Hi I have used some code but I want it so when the name is NULL it is hidden, if this is possible please help.

Here is the code

```
    <p id="top"><strong>Welcome back <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?> [<a href="admin/logout.php">Logout</a>]<br/>Welcome To the homepage of The Journalist's</p>
```

I want it to be when name is NULL, for

```
    "<strong>Welcome back <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?> [<a href="admin/logout.php">Logout</a>]"
```

to be hidden.

Thank you.

update...
This is what i have so far
        This is what i have so far.

```
    <?php
    if ($SESSION['name']= NULL) {
    ?>
    <div><strong>Welcome back <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?> [<a  href="admin/logout.php">Logout</a>]</div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

I have fixed it , thank you for everyone that has commented. for anyone else with this problem. here is my solution.

```
    <?php
    if ($_SESSION['name']!= NULL) {
    ?>
    <strong>Welcome back <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?> [<a href="admin/logout.php">Logout</a>]<br/>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: if you don't want the div at all, then have php NOT output it.

Comment: i want this to show if there is a name there, but when there isnt for it not to show, because the user isnt logged in

Comment: `if (name is not there) { display div }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update from your posted code:

For one, you are using **$SESSION** instead of **$_SESSION**.  Second, you are setting **$SESSION['name']** using a single equal sign, so the if condition would always fail because it is evaluating `if (NULL)`.   You need to use `==` or `===`.  Read up on **[comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)**.

---

```
<?php
if (condition) {
?>
<div></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: This is what i have so far. 

        <?php
if ($SESSION['name']= NULL) {
?>
<div><strong>Welcome back <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?> [<a href="admin/logout.php">Logout</a>]</div>
<?php
}
?>

Comment: You have no div or if in your question so it is hard to know what you have so far.  Edit your question, don't post the current code in a comment.